# ERROR CONSULTA SQL EN DATAGRIDVIEW C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

estoy utilizando la siguiente query para llenar un datagridview con el resultado, pero el resultado que obtengo al ejecutar la consulta es que el datagridView se me llena con todos los datos y no filtra por fechas, alguien sabe donde está el error?

```
 void buscarDatosDiarios()
    {

        string query = "SELECT * FROM diarios WHERE FechaHora BETWEEN '" + dateTimePickerDesde.Text + "' AND '" + dateTimePickerHasta.Text + "' ";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conexion);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter( query, cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dataGridDiarios.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

También he probado lo siguiente con el mismo resultado.Gracias.

```
        string query = "SELECT * FROM diarios WHERE FechaHora >= '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "' AND FechaHora <'" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "' ";
```

Comment: si le pasas la fecha de forma manual te trae bien el resultado?

Comment: no, por que puede ser? es un campo dateTime normal

Comment: vale si le paso la consulta con los datos al reves si que me la ejecuta bien  SELECT * FROM diarios WHERE FechaHora BETWEEN '2020/01/01' AND '2020/01/09' ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SQL Server, si le pasas una fecha como string, se la debes pasar en formato ISO, por ejemplo "Año-Mes-Dia".

```
string fechaDesde = dateTimePickerDesde.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string fechaHasta = dateTimePickerHasta.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string query = "SELECT * FROM diarios WHERE FechaHora BETWEEN '" + fechaDesde  + "' AND '" + fechaHasta  + "' ";
```

Comment: era justo eso, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No le pases al sql server las fechas en formato string. Para esto utiliza parámetros, para que el framework y el motor hablen entre ellos, y así no tendrás problemas con la configuración regional o el idioma asociado a la conexión, etc...., además de realizarlo de un modo quizá, más adecuado.

```
   string query = "SELECT * FROM diarios WHERE FechaHora BETWEEN @paramFechaDesde AND @paramFechaHasta";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conexion))
        {
            //Inicializa el comando que se va a ejecutar
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,cn))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramFechaDesde",   dateTimePickerDesde.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramFechaHasta", dateTimePickerHasta.Value);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridDiarios.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
```

Observa que si introduces los diferentes objetos dentro de sentencias Using, ya no te tienes que preocupar de ejecutar los métodos close y dispose, de los mismos, y liberar los recursos que ya no son necesarios.

Espero te ayude